# sidebar menu icon trimmed when i increase icon size

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I want to have a sidebar menu with only icons, so i want to increase icon size to be more visible managed to increase icons size by putting it `Demens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" 
 tools:override="true">72dp</dimen>
```

this is my menu file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_start_new_trip"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_start_new_trip"

/>

<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_edit_current_trip"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_icon_edit_trip"


/>
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_saved_trip"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_saved_trip"


/>
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_about"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_question_mak"
/>
</group>
```

And this is my DrawerLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

                                           android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_home_map"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                           android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                           tools:openDrawer="start"
                                           android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/map"
                                           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".HomeMapActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

    <include
            android:id="@+id/tbHomeMap"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_home_map" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:id="@+id/guideline16"
                                            android:orientation="horizontal" app:layout_constraintGuide_end="32dp"/>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:id="@+id/guideline17"
                                            android:orientation="vertical" app:layout_constraintGuide_end="16dp"/>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:id="@+id/guideline18"
                                            android:orientation="vertical"
                                            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp"/>

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnHomeIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_page"

        android:background="@null"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline17"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline16"/>
<Button
        android:paddingEnd="10sp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/btnStartNewTrip"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_start_new_trip"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="@drawable/button_baground_blue_no_edge" android:id="@+id/btnStartNewTrip"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnHomeIcon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnHomeIcon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline18"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnHomeIcon"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:menu="@menu/side_bar_navigation_menu"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is the image of the icons when they get trimmed:

[image: Icons Trimed in sidebar menu]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 
but i managed to find a solution here:

In style.xml:

```
resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    .
    .
    .   
    <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">80dp</item>
</style>
```